# POI - Setting sheet as very hidden not working

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am doing some Java code on XLS files using the POI libraries. I am trying to set some sheets as very hidden so users cannot access them at all.

**Definition of very hidden sheet**

http://www.kiranjholla.com/myblog/2010/03/the-very-hidden-sheet-in-excel.html

**Code**

```
    // Creates and hides a sheet
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    HSSFSheet hiddenSheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
    workbook.setSheetHidden(workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName), HSSFWorkbook.SHEET_STATE_VERY_HIDDEN);
```

**Problem**

Unfortunately, when I open the generated Excel files, the sheets I am trying to hide are displayed as hidden, but the users can still access them using the Format -> Sheet -> Show option.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As stated in the API, please note that sheet currently set as active sheet (sheet 0 in a newly created workbook or the one set via setActiveSheet()) cannot be hidden.

Comment: Thank you @MatteoBaldi, I updated my question to be more clear. The sheets are hidden, but can be shown to users with the Format -> Sheet -> Show option.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I am using version 3.15.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want your sheet to be accessed by user you must password protect it before setting it very hidden:

```
    workbook.getSheetAt(0).protectSheet("abc");
    workbook.setSheetHidden(0, HSSFWorkbook.SHEET_STATE_VERY_HIDDEN);
```

Hope it may help

Comment: Deprecated - use workbook.setSheetVisibility(0, SheetVisibility.VERY_HIDDEN);